# Why gradle does not run these tasks in parallel?

Tags: gradle

I am new to gradle and I am trying to create a simple set of tasks. 3 of them should run in parallel (t1, t2, t3). The last one should run after first 3 finish. However gradle is refusing to do any parallel execution and runs them sequentially in order of registration.

The process runs on a redhat linux machine, no IDE is used.

How to allow multi-processing on task executions?

Here is my `build.gradle.kts` file:

```
import org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.*
import org.gradle.api.DefaultTask
import org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskAction
import java.io.File
import java.nio.file.Paths
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture
import org.gradle.api.provider.Provider


plugins {
    `base`
    //id("org.gradle.cache") version "7.3.3"
    id("com.dorongold.task-tree") version "2.1.1"
    //id("org.owasp.dependencycheck") version "9.0.9"
}
tasks.register<Exec>("t1") {
    outputs.file("t1/file1.txt")
    commandLine("bld.bash", "hello world", "t1/file1.txt")
}
tasks.register<Exec>("t2") {
    outputs.file("t2/file2.txt")
    commandLine("bld.bash", "hello world", "t2/file2.txt")
}
tasks.register<Exec>("t3") {
    outputs.file("t3/file3.txt")
    commandLine("bld.bash", "hello world", "t3/file3.txt")
}

tasks.register<Exec>("asm") {
    outputs.file("asm/asm.txt")
    dependsOn("t1", "t2", "t3")
    inputs.files("t1/file1.txt", "t2/file2.txt", "t3/file3.txt")
    commandLine("asm.bash", "t1/file1.txt", "t2/file2.txt", "t3/file3.txt", "asm/asm.txt")
}

tasks.named("build") {
    dependsOn("asm")
}
```

`gradle.properties`:

```
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.caching=true
```

The script it executes just has a long delay, so that I can understand that tasks run in parallel or not:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 10
echo "$1" > $2
echo "$2 created"
```

Running `gradlew build` with or without --parallel with or without --max-workers has no effect.

Thank you for advice.

Comment: I think that's unfortunately how it is supposed to be: "To execute tasks belonging to different **subprojects** in parallel, use the `--parallel` flag" (also https://stackoverflow.com/q/53042396/995891)

Comment: So, you are saying that the only way to run tasks in parallel is to put them in different subprojects?

Comment: That seems to be the only workaround, yes

Comment: Thanks, I tried, it definitely worked. The only problem is that this approach is impractical in my case. There is no way to split all tasks existing in my project into subprojects. A simple analogous example is a custom c++ library task with parallel compilation of sources.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in a comment, generally speaking parallel tasks still only happen when in different subprojects / modules.

If you want to run things in parallel within a single project, you'll likely have to have to leverage the Worker API - which, fair warning, will have a bit of boilerplate.

- https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/worker_api.html

Note that while the examples in that document place the custom code within their own source directory, you should still be able to just add the classes/interfaces directly in your build script (especially if its small)